# Satisfying as many constraints as possible in prolog

Tags: prolog

I am trying to satisfy as many constraints as possible given by a user.

**Code:**

```
findall(Option, execute(List, ListItems, T, Option, ListItems), Gathered).

execute([],_,_,_,_).

execute([_|Rest], [], Pref, Answer, Backup):-
    execute_combinations(Rest, Backup, Pref, Answer, Backup).

execute(Combinations, [H|T], Pref, Answer, Backup):-
    [Pref_Airlines, Pref_Timings, Pref_Stops] = Pref,
    [Start|_] = Combinations,
    [FlightNo, _, _, _] = H,
    (
        member(airlines, Start), satisfy_airline(FlightNo, Pref_Airlines);
        member(timings, Start), satisfy_time(FlightNo, Pref_Timings);
        member(stops, Start), satisfy_stops(FlightNo, Pref_Stops);
    ),
    Option = H;
    execute(Combinations, T, Pref, Option).
```

---

**Description:**

`List/Combinations` contains combinations of `(airline, timings, stops)`, these are of the form:

`[airline, timings, stops], [airline, timings], [timings, stops], [stops], [airline], etc..`

`findall` is being used to collect the successful options.

`ListItems` contains nested list of the form `[FlightNo, X, Y, Z]`.

`satisfy_*` predicates work fine and return true or false based on the arguments.

---

**Question:**
In the code above, the problem I am having is that i want to execute the respective `satisfy_*` predicate only if it is in the `Start` which is verified by `member/2` variable.

So if `Start` contains `[airline, stops]`, then only `satisfy_airline` and `satisfy_stops` must execute.

Hope I made myself clear and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `forall/2`.

```
forall((member(X,Start),
       member((X,Pred,Pref),[(airlines,satisfy_airline,Pref_Airlines), ...])),
      call(Pred,FlightNo,Pref))
```

"..." because I was lazy. Just triples of the atom, the corresponding satisfy predicate and the corresponding preferences. This goes in place of all of the member / satisfy goals.

Let me know if this doesn't work, I'm not especially confident...

EDIT: If that doesn't work then you could just do this, though it isn't very pretty :

```
(
   (member(airlines,Start) -> satisfy_airlines(FlightNo,Pref_Airlines) ; true),
   (member(timings,Start) -> satisfy_times(FlightNo,Pref_Timings) ; true),
   (member(stops,Start) -> satisfy_stops(FlightNo,Pref_Stops) ; true)
)
```